# Are the expressions: "You needn't" and "You don't need to" different in meaning?

Tags: meaning, differences, ambiguity

While doing some research on a comment I had read on ELL, I read the following excerpt from a website called [e.grammar](http://www.e-grammar.org/infinitive-gerund/)

> You needn't listen to him. (You don't have to listen to him.) x You
> don't need to listen to him. (There is no need to listen.) These two sentences are different in the form and meaning, too.

After reflecting, I started interpreting the two sentences like this:

1. **"You needn't listen to him"** = It is unnecessary to listen to that
   man. If you want to listen that is your choice, but it's not
   important.
2. **"You don't *need* to listen to him"** = It is not *necessary* to
   listen to that man. If you do you will only be wasting your time.

Is the second sentence more forceful, perhaps precluding the possibility of choice? Or is my mind playing tricks on me and in reality the two phrases have identical meanings?

I must admit to feeling bemused. Before reading the passage I would have said there was no difference in meaning between **needn't** and **don't need**. On the [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv317.shtml) I read this:

> **Needn't and don't need to**
>
> There is also a difference in use when
> these verbs are used to describe present situations. We can use both
> **needn't** and **don't need** to to give permission to someone not to do
> something in the immediate future. We can also use **need** as a noun
> here:
>
> You **don't need** to water the garden this evening. It's going to
> rain tonight.
> You **needn't** water the garden this evening. It's going
> to rain tonight.
> There's **no need** to water the garden this evening.
> It's going to rain tonight.

This would confirm my initial belief; that there is no real difference in meaning but now... I'm not so sure. And if there is no difference, except for structure, why do the two forms exist side by side? Why or when did "need" become a modal verb?

Comment: When did need become a modal verb? That's a misleading question. The real question is: when did it ***stop being*** a modal verb? See [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need+not+go%2Cdo+not+need+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). (Actually, it was only a modal verb in the negative, and not generally used in the positive; *need not* and *must not* being two different opposites of the modal verb *must*. There's a question about that somewhere on this site.)

Comment: My question was dictated by the website I consulted. It claims that the two uses are different in form and in meaning, too. As I am a trusting soul, I began to doubt my instincts and almost convinced myself it was true! However, my second question, poorly researched I admit, was also interesting for me.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it shows more research effort that the linked duplicate.

Comment: @JJJ and curiously, it also has more views too. But then, logically, the older question should be closed as a duplicate of this one... hmm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a teacher of English as a Foreign Language, my take on it is that the differences are too small to be of interest to anyone except linguists, poets, and authors.

There is, however, one difference that you accidentally highlighted. Notice the stress you placed on *need* in your second example sentence:

> **"You don't *need* to listen to him."**

You could have just as easily placed the stress on *don't*, or not stressed any of the words. You have fewer choices of sentence stress in the *you needn't* form, and this probably affects the nuance in ways I'm not really qualified to discuss.

> Why or when did "need" become a modal verb?

There is a large grey area between the modal auxiliaries and the ordinary verbs. The trend seems to be that, in forms like:

> *subject*  *verb1*  *verb2*

*verb1* tends to get reanalysed as a modal auxiliary. For instance, *will* used to be a plain verb, meaning *want to* (and *want* used to mean *lack*).

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in meaning.  But you needn't speak like that if you live in the States or they may mistake you for a Brit.

My apologies. Let me clarify what I was meaning in the sentence above. It is really a  matter of dialect.  It is not nearly as common in the States to hear "you needn't" as it would be in England (and therefore one may mistake you for a 'Brit'). I upped your comment for making me aware of my cause of confusion & hoped it would alert you that I attempted to answer your question (sorry I'm new and don't know how to chat).

Comment: You needn't speak like what/how? And why may you be mistaken for a Brit?

Comment: Oh here it is. I hope that makes more sense. I have a penchant for being a smart a**. No offense.  I looked at your page & noticed you were from across the pond. I play words w/friends with someone in England and constantly inform him he has an advantage because I am an American and therefore brutalize the English language ;-)

Comment: That was the first thing that came to mind: Brit.